# AWS API Gateway not able to call AWS Lambda function using JSON Array payload

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have defined a resource/method in API Gateway to make a post call to Lambda Function which is a microservice exposing few endpoints.

Method: post

Payload:

```json
[{"gts_user_id":2,"gts_role_id":2,"gts_user_role_is_primary":1}]
```

[image]

This call is not reaching the Lambda method. I am not able to see any logs.
What may be the reasons?

Comment: Can you show a picture of the API GW Resources, show us the API GW POST pointing to the Lambda. Second are you using Velocity Apache - its the language used to do ETL's on incoming and outgoing JSON? Have you looked  in Cloud Watch > Log Groups > /aws/lambda/user ? The Error will be there...

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for quick response. How to attach a picture? Please share your emailID, I will send the picture. I am using Springboot microservice. Inside Cloud Watch > Log Groups > /aws/lambda/IdentitityService, there is no log. It is working if I pass a plain JSON object and not an array.

Comment: I added the picture in google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ouCCZPipfWabGRTnrm4N4cWuF-x_gShj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I did remove the URL @MonoranjanGorai. It was broken and contained details. Furthermore, your picture that you linked is a Word document.

Comment: Thanks Jens, are you able to understand the issue?

Comment: Here is my article on aws lambda and API gateway plz check - https://dzone.com/articles/aws-lambda-with-mysql-rds-and-api-gateway

Comment: Thanks Jens for the articles. It didn't give direct solution. But after analyzing and exploring several options I found that there was plolicy error "The final policy size (20577) is bigger than the limit (20480)". I removed the triggers & recreated, then it started to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But after analyzing and exploring several options I found that there was policy error "The final policy size (20577) is bigger than the limit (20480)". I removed the triggers & recreated, then it started to work.